# RHEL/Apache ssl.conf configuration problem

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

We've got multiple subdomains, each with it's own virtualhost entry in httpd.conf and (for those supporting https) in ssl.conf as well.  Our main www subdomain has a GoDaddy cert associated with it.  The subdomain I'm configuring right now on our dev server ("api.bulbstorm.com") has an ssl.conf virtualhost entry that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 172.16.247.153:443>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/api"
  ServerName api.bulbstorm.com:443
  ErrorLog logs/api-error_log
  CustomLog logs/api-access_log common
  LogLevel warn
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCertificateFile /var/www/certs/api/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/certs/api/server.key
  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>
  <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Directory>
  <Directory "/var/www/api">
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
  php_value include_path "/var/www/inc"
  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
    "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

... the crt & key files in /var/www/certs/api/ were generated using openssl per instructions found [here](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html).

The api subdomain originally pointed to the godaddy cert for the www subdomain.  But even though I've changed the virtualhost entry associated with the api subdomain to point to the self-signed certificate/key pair (and have restarted httpd, completely cleared browser settings related to the previous exception for the godaddy cert, etc.) browsers are still throwing warnings saying that the cert is for the www domain.  When I look at the cert the browsers are pulling it looks like they're still getting the godaddy cert.

Higher up in the ssl.conf file there are these lines:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

This cert/key pair is different than the godaddy cert/key pair referenced in the virtualhost entry for the www subdomain, which looks like this:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/www.bulbstorm.com_ssl/www.bulbstorm.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/www.bulbstorm.com_ssl/www.bulbstorm.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/www.bulbstorm.com_ssl/gd_intermediate_bundle.crt
```

Any light that anyone can shed on the issue I'm having will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll get a better response on serverfault.com.  I must admit that I hate the way they make you switch sites and repost your question, but that's the way they made this system...  sigh...

Comment: ... yeah, I was wondering about that.  I'll repost on serverfault and close here.  thx.

Comment: +1 vote to close as "belongs on systemfault"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "answer" to this question was to repost it on serverfault.com.

Comment: you could have [linked it](http://serverfault.com/questions/45433/rhel-apache-ssl-conf-configuration-issue)